# ordering across partitions in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am writing a kafka producer and needs help in creating partitions.
I have a group and a user table. Group contains different users and at a time a user can be a part of only one group.

There can be two types of events which I will receive as input and based on that I will add them to Kafka.

1. The events related to users.
2. The events related to groups.

Whenever an event related to a group happens, all the users in that group must be updated in bulk at consumer end.
Whenever an event related to a user happens, it must be executed as such at the consumer end.

Also, I want to maintain ordering on basis of time.

If I create user level partitioning, then the bulk update won't be possible at consumer end.

If I create group level partitioning, then the parallel update of user events won't happen.

I am trying to figure out the possibilities I can try here.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, I want to maintain ordering on basis of time.

Means that topics, no matter how many, cannot have more than one partition, as you could have received messages out-of-order.

Obviously, unless you implement something like sequence ids in your messages (and can share that sequence across possibly multiple producers).

> If I create user level partitioning, then the bulk update won't be possible at consumer end.
>
> If I create group level partitioning, then the parallel update of user events won't happen.

It sounds like a very simple messaging design, where you have a single queue (that's actually backed by a single topic with a single partition) that's consumed by multiple users. Actually any pub-sub messaging technology would be sufficient here (e.g. RabbitMQ's fanout exchanges).

The messages on the queue contain the information whether they are `group updates` or `user updates` - the consumers then filter the input depending on what they are interested in.

To discuss an alternative: single queue for `group updates`, and another for `user updates` - I understand that it would not be enough due to order demands - it's possible to get a `group update` independently of `user update`, breaking the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

From the kafka documentation :
https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#intro_consumers

> Kafka only provides a total order over records within a partition, not
>   between different partitions in a topic. Per-partition ordering
>   combined with the ability to partition data by key is sufficient for
>   most applications. However, if you require a total order over records
>   this can be achieved with a topic that has only one partition, though
>   this will mean only one consumer process per consumer group.

so the best you can do is to have single partition-single topic.